# Android supported codec means software codec?

Tags: android, codec, aac

I know that two types of codecs exist - Hardware codec and Software codec.

And  [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) displays  Android supported codecs.

I would like to know if a codec is listed in supported media formats, does it mean it is a software codec? For example, if it is mentioned that **AAC LC codec** supported by Android(Android supported codec) and my hardware does not support **AAC LC** codec, can I play **AAC LC** audio music ?

Answer (score 1):

All Android devices have to support the list of codecs in [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Android has CTS tests to check if these formats are supported by a device.

However this can be done using either software or hardware codec. Typically, video is supported using hardware codec whereas audio is supported in software as audio needs less processing power.

In your case, even if the hardware does not support AAC LC, the device will decode using software codec library.